# mvc - reusing service behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, dependency-injection

I have been working on a MVC-EF application. We use DI container to inject dependencies into controllers, services, and repositories i.e across the UI-Services-DataAccess layers.

My question is regarding DI in services. One thing I have been confused about recently has been arisen from the need to use the behaviour (aka methods) that was implemented in one service in another service.

As far as I know, one service should not take dependency upon another because that would finally be leading closer to circular dependency and hence causing issues for DI container down the line.

So my question is, how should I work this out?

Should I be implementing the needed behaviour in second service (as part of its own methods) or I can somehow reuse it from the already implemented first service?

Can DI container help me in this regard?

Or is it that the way out is to outsource behaviour implemented in services into a separate Business Logic Layer, so it is available to each of the services? BTW, we currently do not have a separate BLL.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, one service should not take dependency upon another because that would finally be leading closer to circular dependency and hence causing issues for DI container down the line.

This isn't *quite* true. In general, your objects refer to each other, forming a **graph**. When we discuss Dependency Injection, we normally call it a **Dependency Graph**.

As long as this graph is a [Directed Acyclic Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), all is good. The keyword here is *acyclic*, but it doesn't preclude *reuse*. You can have several services that use a single instance of another service; that just means that the service is **shared**.

Dependency Graphs can be as shallow or as deep as required, as long as they are acyclic, you can [compose dependency graphs with confidence](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence).

Comment: But isn't it easy to lose path with those complex interrelated requirements arriving on the table?

I thought initially to implement the same way, having concept of downstream and upstream services in mind. But then thought it is easy to get corrupted very soon, with all sorts of interrelated requirements that arrive in future.

Answer (score 0):

As usual the answer is, "It depends", however based on what you have said regarding needing some behavior/method to be available to multiple services, I think the last approach you mentioned makes the most sense.

Creating an independent class for "Support" functions can be useful in a lot of scenarios, particularly if you have methods that are a used for several services. DI should then be able to help you provide the "Support" class to its dependents.